# How to append every day data to the tabels in the big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are migrating from Digital Ocean to GCP and to test things out we  exported our data as json from our mongo DB and uploaded it to GCS bucket (userDump.json is one of it)

Now, we are fetching data from our GCS bucket and making tables in big query. (users table)

So far everything is working out.

My problem:

Every day we are onboarding new users and their data is saved on GCS. We want to run a cron /similar functionality to add  that data to the table so in the morning, people can perform queries on yesterday's data.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: With BigQuery Data Transfer Service[1], you are able to create a daily data transfer job from GCS to BigQuery. 


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-service-overview

Comment: related discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/d50wo9/how_to_append_every_day_data_to_the_tabels_in_the/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my lazy data loading in BigQuery article:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6

What you could do is:

- Have BigQuery read files directly from GCS - a federated query.
- Then have a scheduled query inside BigQuery materialize these federated tables into native BigQuery tables.
- Your users will get fresh data daily, or even more frequently - no servers needed :).